# Python: Read csv file with an arbitrary number of tabs as delimiter

Tags: python, csv, tabs

I have my csv file formatted with all columns nicely alligned by using one or more tabs in between different values.

I know it is possible to use a single tab as delimiter with `csv.register_dialect("tab_delimiter", delimiter="\t")`. But this only works with exaclty one tab between the values. I would like to process the file keeping its format, i.e., not deleting duplicate tabs. Each field (row, column) contains a value.

Is it possible to use a number of 1+ tabs as delimiter or ignore additional tabs without affecting the numbering of the values in a row? `row[1]` should be the second value independent of how many tabs are in between `row[0]`.

Comment: Reading the docs I gather that you can only use a single character as a delimiter. I guess your best option is to preprocess the file to remove duplicate tabs.

Comment: Provided that every row has data for every column, just with varying numbers of tabs as delimiters, you can just process this with a list comprehension `separated = [item for item in row if item]` where `row` is a row in your `csv.reader()`. If some rows have blank entries then I don't see any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

```
##Sample.txt
##ID    name    Age
##1 11  111
##2     22  222


import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Sample.txt' ,sep=r'\t+')
print df
```

Comment: Any way to make this work with `csv` instead of `pandas`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there will never be empty fields, you can use a generator to remove duplicates from the incoming CSV file and then use the `csv` module as usual:

```
import csv

def de_dup(f, delimiter='\t'):
    for line in f:
        yield delimiter.join(field for field in line.split(delimiter) if field)

with open('data.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(de_dup(f), delimiter='\t'):
        print(row)
```

An alternative way is to use `re.sub()` in the generator:

```
import re

def de_dup(f, delimiter='\t'):
    for line in f:
        yield re.sub(r'{}{{2,}}'.format(delimiter), delimiter, line)
```

but this still has the limitation that all fields must contain a value.

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient way for me to deal with the multiple tabs was using an additonal function that takes the row and removes the empty values/fields that are created by multiple tabs in a row. This doesn't affect the formating of the csv-file and I can access the second value in the row with `row[1]` - even with multiple tabs before it.

```
def remove_empty(line):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(line)):
        if line[i] != "":
            result.append(line[i])
    return result
```

And in the code where I read the file and process the values:

```
for row in reader:
    row = remove_empty(row)
    **continue processing normally**
```

I think this solution is similar to mhawke's, but with his solution I couldn't access the same values with `row[i]` as before (i.e., with only one delimiter in between each value).

Answer (score 0):

Or the completely general solution for any type of repeated separators is to recursively replace each multiple separator by single separator and write to a new file (although it is slow for gigabyte sized CSV files):

```
def replaceMultipleSeparators( fileName, oldSeparator, newSeparator ):
  linesOfCsvInputFile = open( fileName, encoding='utf-8', mode='r' ).readlines()

  csvNewFileName = fileName + ".new"
  print('Writing:   %s replacing %s with %s' % ( csvNewFileName, oldSeparator, newSeparator ) , end='' )
  outputFileStream = open( newFileName, 'w' )
  for line in linesOfCsvInputFile:
    newLine = line.rstrip()
    processedLine = ""
    while newLine != processedLine:
      processedLine = newLine
      newLine = processedLine.replace( oldSeparator + oldSeparator, oldSeparator )
    newLine = newLine.replace( oldSeparator, newSeparator )
    outputFileStream.write( newLine + '\n' )
  outputFileStream.close()
```

which given input testFile.csv will generator testFile.csv.new with TABs replaced by PIPEs if you run:

```
replaceMultipleSeparators( 'testFile.csv', '\t', '|' )
```

Sometimes you will need to replace 'utf-8' encoding with 'latin-1' for some microsoft US generated CSV files. See errors related to 0xe4 reading for this issue.